# Inject an input component in form component : No provider for NgForm

Tags: angular

I wish to inject an input component in form component from the top component and validate the input.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-template-form?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild-input%2Fchild-input.component.ts

But I can't bind the form with the entry, so the form not validate the input
Or if I add the following code in the input component :

`viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }]`

I have this error :

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ControlContainer -> NgForm]:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ControlContainer -> NgForm]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for NgForm!
```

Any idea or other approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Forget about this providers, you have to query the content children and then register the inputs in your form.

1. **child-input.component.ts**

You must get the reference for the NgModel that you are using inside the component and also provide a Input for a name. This name will differentiate this specific field from the others inside the form.

```
@ViewChild(NgModel, { static: false }) ngModel: any;
@Input() name: string;

// your input must have the name property bound here
<input #firstnameControl="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="firstname" [name]="name" required>
```

2. **parent-form.component.ts**

Ok, so here we'll need some different things to wire it up. Start getting the reference for the form and also all the controls you intend to inject dynamically.

```
@ContentChildren(ChildInputComponent) inputs: QueryList<any>;
@ViewChild('formulaire') form: NgForm;
```

Here we are getting only the inputs of type `ChildInputComponent`, but if you want to create more different inputs then you can create a directive and use it as the selector for the inputs.

After getting the references we need to register the inputs inside our form:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    // iterate over the dynamic inputs
    this.inputs.forEach(input => {
         console.log(input);
         // register them into our form
         this.form.addControl(input.ngModel);
    });

    // this line is optional, use it to test and check the state of the form
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)
}
```

3. Using your form

Now that you have finished those steps, you are able to use it like this:

```
<app-parent-form>
    <app-child-input name="title">
    </app-child-input>

    <app-child-input name="email">
    </app-child-input>
</app-parent-form>
```

Full example here: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-template-form-brp617